# Filter a Map with mutableList values

Tags: kotlin, maps, nullable, nullable-reference-types, mutablelist

I have the following map object :

```
var myStringMap = mapOf(10 to mutableListOf<String>(),11 to mutableListOf<String>(), 12 to mutableListOf<String>())
```

I want to append files from a source to the corresponding key as follows :

```
  myStringMap.keys.forEach { key ->
    getStringFromSource(source, user).let {
      if (it != null) {
        myStringMap[key]!!.add(it)
       }
    }
  }
```

The thing is that I need to add !! else the editor is complaining about a safe call for nullable object. Why is that ?

After that, when I want to filter the keys whose values are empty I have a typing error as long as GetBytes has **MutableList?** .

```
myStringMap.filter { (_: Int, value) -> value.isNotEmpty() }.let {
      it.keys.forEach { key ->
        val bytes = GetBytes(it[key])
        allBytes.add(bytes)
      }
}
```

Why is that? the **it** context should be Map<Int,MutableList>?
Probably I should convert the mutableList to a list?

Comment: Are you trying to add the same string to every key of the map? Or does `getStringFromSource` return something different every time it's called?

Comment: In the code starting with `myStringMap.filter`, where did you get an error? What is the error message? What is the type of `allBytes`?

Comment: The error is that the editor tells me that it[key]  is of type Map<Int,MutableList>?  . To me this should be Map<Int,MutableList> since I am filtering.

Comment: Also I do not understand why myStringMap[key]!!.add(it) needs !! 
getStringFromSource returns a string and I want to append that string to the mutableList for that given key

Comment: @JPV I cannot reproduce "`it[key]` is of type `Map<Int,MutableList>?`". It is `MutableList<String>?` as expected for me.

Comment: The main issue here is that looking up a key in a map can _always_ fail. In this case, we're iterating through the map's keys, so they _should_ always be present — but the compiler can't tell that. (And even if it could, there's always the risk that other code, possibly in another thread, has removed that entry in between. Or that there's a bug in the map implementation.) So `get()` (and hence `[…]`) can always return null. That's why you have to add `!!` — (cont.)

Comment: — though it would be safer (and probably more efficient) to use some other approach, e.g. iterating through the map's [entries](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/entries.html) instead of its keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `it[key]` still returns a nullable type even when you pass in something from its `keys` collection? Well, because that is what the [`get`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/get.html) method of `Map` is declared to return. It doesn't depend on the value you pass in.

The key thing to realise here is that you are trying to do something to each of the *values* of the map, which are all mapped to a key. You are trying to add an element to each of the values, which are lists. You should access `values`, not `keys`.

If `getStringFromSource` has side effects, e.g. returns a different string every time you call it, you can do:

```
myStringMap.values.forEach { value ->
    getStringFromSource(source, user)?.let { value.add(it) }
}
```

If `getStringFromSource` does not have side effects, you can call it first:

```
getStringFromSource(source, user)?.let { string ->
    myStringMap.values.forEach { it.add(string) }
}
```

If you actually meant `getStringFromSource(source, key)`, then you should operate on `entries`, which gives you both the key and value to work with:

```
myStringMap.entries.forEach { (key, value) ->
    getStringFromSource(source, key)?.let { value.add(it) }
}
```

This applies to the second situation too. It seems like you are trying to do something with each of the values, so just access the `values`, not the `keys`.

```
 myStringMap.filterValues(List<String>::isNotEmpty).values.forEach { 
      allBytes.add(GetBytes(it)) 
 }
```

Comment: May be worth adding that if OP wants to use the key in setting the corresponding value (which I suspect was the intent), then probably better to start from `myStringMap.`[`entries`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/entries.html) (which gives you each key with its corresponding value) rather than `myStringMap.`[`values`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/values.html).

Comment: @gidds Ah, so you mean one of `source`, `user` should have been `key`? Indeed that is the more common scenario :)

Comment: Awesome @Sweeper. That was a great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Use the filter that you need:

- `filter`
- `first`
- ...

and them `let` example:

> mutableList.first { it.isSelected == false }.let { this?.isSelected = true }